# list of strings to list of doubles java

Tags: java, string, double

I have a data file containing a combination of doubles and strings like this:

```
Rmax=2.3
Rmin=1.0
```

etc.

I'm using split() to cut out the = like this:

```
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String phrase = strLine;                
            try {
                //splits to variable name, value
                String[] parsed = phrase.split("[=]");                      
                int parsed[0].toString() = parsed[1];

            } catch (PatternSyntaxException e) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

Now i'm trying to get the values initialized so that parsed[0] becomes the name of the integer and parsed[1] becomes the value. equivalent to the initializer 
int name = value;

obviously the line

```
int parsed[0].toString() = parsed[1];
```

doesn't work. how do i go about doing this?

Comment: You should use a HashMap<String, Double> for what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this

```
Map<String, Double> map = new HashMap<String,Double>()
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    //splits to variable name, value
    String[] parsed = phrase.split("=");
    String name = parsed[0];
    double value = Double.parseDouble(parsed[1]);
    map.put(name, value);
}
```

As has been mentioned you have to catch NumberFormatException and handle a missing '=' depending on whether these are possible.

If you know all possible fields you could use an enum for the field name.

---

Instead of using a Map you could use an Object which you set via reflection.

```
class Config {
    double Rmax;
    double Rmin;
    // add more fields here.
}

Config config = new Config;
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    //splits to variable name, value
    String[] parsed = phrase.split("=");
    try {
       String name = parsed[0];
       double value = Double.parseDouble(parsed[1]);
       Config.class.getField(name).setDouble(value);
    } catch (Exception e) {
       // log exception.
    }
}
```

Comment: I would use big-D `Double` so he can then put the values into a `Map<String,Double>` like others have suggested, but `parseDouble()` is the way I would go.  Also, you'll have to catch a `NumberFormatException` in case the value on the RHS of the equals sign is not formatted as a number (for example, "Rmax=1s" or "Rmin=two", or other such silly things).

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a [HashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

With a hash map you can set Key value with what ever types you want. In this case you want

```
HashMap<String, Double> map = new HashMap<String,Double>()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can read it to a [`Properties`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) object and do the conversion from there:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load( /* your file as InputStream */ );
Map<String, Double> parsed = new HashMap<String, Double>();
for(Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry : props.entrySet()){
    parsed.put(entry.getKey().toString(),
    Double.valueOf(entry.getValue().toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
  String theName = parsed[0];
  double theValue = Double.parseDouble(parsed[1]);
```